# View memory consumed by process on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, memory

is there any command/tool on windows 7 to see the memory consumed by a process in bytes, just like tasklist/taskmanager, but in bytes?

Answer (score 3):

You can run:

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\plop.txt PROCESS get *
```

Open up plop.txt and pick the info (fields) your interested in then use:

```
WMIC PROCESS where name="csrss.exe" get caption,PeakVirtualSize,PageFileUsage,PeakWorkingSetSize
```

Output:

```
Caption    PageFileUsage  PeakVirtualSize  PeakWorkingSetSize
csrss.exe  1961984        86114304         29220864
```

Comment: +1 for 'plop.txt'. I think I'll use that next time I need a temporary file name.

Comment: Nice. What is the param to see the amount of memory used in bytes?

Comment: I would say `WorkingSetSize` (They are described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) has a bunch of tools that can help you.

Comment: Specifically, the "Process Explorer" (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will do exactly that, and far more as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about [get-process cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176855.aspx) for powershell?